# Google contacts sync issue with Lenovo Vibe K5

Tags: contacts, sync, google, lenovo

I have Lenovo Vibe K5. I have several contacts in my Google account, and tried to sync them to my phone. I'm suffering from two issues.

**Issue 1:**

Contacts with same name (with possible permutations) were not syncing. Look at the examples to understand better.

**Example 1:**
In google, if I have these contacts:

```
Ram Kumar - 9876543210
Kumar Ram - 9876543211
```

then, only one of the two gets synced to my phone. I got only `Kumar Ram` synced in phone.

Even though, after syncing, if I delete `Kumar Ram` in Google contacts, and re-sync in phone, only `Kumar Ram` gets deleted and `Ram Kumar` doesn't appear though. It appears only after deleting the account from phone and re-add and sync again.

*Example 2:*

In google, if I have these contacts:

```
Rahul Sharma - 9876543210
Mirza Sania - 9876543211
Sharma Rahul - 9876543212
Sania Mirza - 9876543213
```

then, only `Sharma Rahul` and `Sania Mirza` gets synced.

Again, just deleting the `Sharma Rahul` in Google contacts, and re-sync in phone won't fetch `Rahul Sharma` to my phone. I need to delete my Google account from phone and re-add and sync again.

Note: *All contact numbers are unique.* Also, tried syncing in other android mobiles, it works perfect. The issue only happens in Lenovo Vibe K5.

**Follow up issue:**

When I add some contacts (similar to Issue 1 with such contacts) to my Google account from my phone, the contacts gets added, synced to Google accounts, but, got DELETED from the phone's contacts (under google account). It appears only in Google contacts website. Syncing again and again, but it doesn't appear in phone's google contacts area.

Add these two contacts in phone under Google account :

```
Ram Kumar - 9876543210
Kumar Ram - 9876543211
```

Sync now, and both gets added to Google. But, one among them or, sometimes both gets DELETED from phone (under google accounts contacts). **[Issue 1's case again]**

*Case 1:* Add first contact, sync, and then add second contact - now only one contact will be deleted in phone. (In the above example, `Kumar Ram` gets deleted.)

*Case 2:* Add both contacts, and then sync - now both contacts gets deleted from phone.

It will only appear in Google contacts web version. Never ever in your phone. If you remove the account from your phone and re-add and sync, then Issue 1 will occur.

This issue happens only in Vibe K5. Tried same Google account on other phones, it synced perfect.

How can I fix these?

Comment: Added examples for each cases. Please ask if you need more information.

Comment: Due to name similarities Google must be syncing the contacts thinking they are are duplicates of each other hence it's syncing only one. Try login to [Contacts Google](http://google.com/contacts) and check if they suggest to merge duplicates to you.

Comment: No, the numbers are unique. Google do not merge such contacts too. Also, this issue happens only in Lenovo Vibe K5 with their custom Vibe UI (dialer / contacts). Tried the same in other phones, but this issue doesn't happen.